# PL/SQL weekly Aggregation Logic with dynamic time range

Tags: oracle, plsql

I need to aggregate the values at weekly interval. My date range is dynamic means i can give any start date and end date. Every sunday should be the starting week of every month. say if i have two columns and my start and end date is 07/11/2016 to 13/11/2016

```
       column A                            column B
     07/11/2016                              23
     08/11/2016                              20
     09/11/2016                              10
     10/11/2016                              05
     11/11/2016                              10
     12/11/2016                              20
     13/11/2016                              10
```

My result should come like taking the average of column B

```
  Column A                       Column B
 13/11/2016                       14.00
```

It means i should consider the past value and aggregate it to the day Sunday of that week. Also if my start and end date is like 07/11/2016 to 10/11/2016 then I should not aggregate the value as my week is not complete. I am able to aggregate the values but if my week is not complete i m not able to restrict the aggregation.
Is there any way to do this in PL/SQL??

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are any of your weeks missing data, even if the start and end of the week are both present?

Comment: Perhaps you just need an extra predicate of `and end_date - start_date >= 7`?

Comment: Why do you want a stored procedure?

Comment: No. data is not missing. This is required for reporting purpose as i use PL/SQL functions in the reports.

Comment: every Sunday should be consider as the starting day of the week for every month. Suppose taking NOV month in consideration. My week should start with 6th NOV. i need to aggregate the values from the 1st NOV till 6th NOV and put it into 6th NOV if my start date is 1 NOV and end date is 6 NOV. But if my starting date is 1st NOV and end date is 7th NOV then my aggregation should take place till 6th NOV only. as my next week is not completed so i don't want to aggregate the value.

Answer (score 0):

```
select to_char(columnA, 'iw') as weeknumber, avg(columnB) 
  from table 
  group by to_char(columnA, 'iw');
```

This will aggregate by number of week. If you need to show last day of week as a label you can get it as `max(columnA) over (partition by to_char(columnA, 'iw'))`

Comment: This will not help. As i have to check based on my start and end date that the week is complete or not.

Comment: My code is like                                                                                                   SELECT decode(p_smp_sz,'week',
                  ((trunc(datetime,'IW') - 1) + Interval '7' DAY)) from datetime_table ded WHERE ded.datetime + v_timezone_offset >= p_frm_dt
            AND ded.datetime + v_timezone_offset <= p_to_dt